# Como enviar dados de um formulário para um email, sendo eu o receptor dos dados e o cliente recebendo uma confirmação de envio no e-mail dele?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

estouy desenvolvendo um site usando bootstrap, e quero entrar nessa área.

Fiz um formulario de orçamento condendo os inputs: Nome, Telefone, E-mail, Mensagem contendo detalhes e o tipo serviço (Usando Check box).

No final, um botão de enviar.

Ai está minha dúvida,

quero que o cliente quando clique em enviar, receba um email de confirmação. e eu receba em meu e-mail os dados do formulario.

Faço isso só usando JS?

Muito Obrigado pessoal!

Comment: Ainda não entendi muito bem, não tem como usar somente com html e JS?

Comment: Para efetuar esse processo, você deve utilizar uma linguagem de programação como: php, asp classic, c#, etc..., e no código dessa linguagem configurar dois ou mais envios com textos diferentes, somente com o javascript eu não conheço.

Comment: achei um tal de mandrill que tem API e dá pra fazer tudo com javascript, porém eu não recomendo pois qualquer pessoa pode obter o e-mail no código javascript, segue o link: https://medium.com/@mariusc23/send-an-email-using-only-javascript-b53319616782

Comment: tem esse Nodemailer, link: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp, procura no google dessa forma: send mail javascript

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou tentar colocar as soluções postas aqui, e vou mantê-los informados.